# Do Breadcrumbs and Views interact in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal

So I'm trying to add a breadcrumb to a Drupal view, but it isn't working. It is coming up as

**Home >> View item**

Which isn't what I want. I want it to be something like:

**Home >> Catalog >> Class of Items >> General Type of Items >> Specific Type of Items >> View item**

Currently, this all works UP TO the view item. Once you click on the view item, it defaults to the top breadcrumb layout.

Why is this, and how can I fix it?

Here's the code used to generate:

```
function CLIENTNAME_preprocess_breadcrumb(&$variables) {
    if (!empty($variables['breadcrumb'])) {
        // Adding the title of the current page to the breadcrumb.
        $variables['breadcrumb'][] = drupal_get_title();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use <code>http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs</code> but seems that you have your custom logics so you need to implement how to get ALL parent pages titles of ALL levels between Home and Item. If you can provide how it is been build (views with arguments, pure taxonomy or other ways) maybe I could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't supported under Drupal. You need to use a custom module called "Custom Breadcrumbs"